# Python array conversion, decimal to hex

Tags: python, arrays, hex, decimal

How do I change my dec_array (eg dec-array = 50, 123, 175, 13) into a hex_array (32, 7B, AF, OA)? The hex() function only works with single characters.

Comment: *The hex() function only works with single characters.* - Huh?

Comment: Write your input and output in syntactically correct Python, please, so we know what you really want. And say what numbers can be in the input. Negatives? Non-integers?

Comment: At the mo I have......

Comment: positive intergers only in dec array & hex_array=[hex(x)[2:] for x in dec_array]

Comment: print dec_array gives [80, 66, 67, 86, 53, 49, 46, 48, 123, 175, 13] and print hex_array gives ['50', '42', '43', '56', '35', '31', '2e', '30', '7b', 'af', 'd'] but I would like [50, 40, 43, 56, 35, 31, 2E, 30, 7B, AF, 0D]

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehensions would probably be the easiest way of doing this:

```
hex_array = [hex(x) for x in dec_array]
```

And if you want to remove the `0x` at the beginning of each element:

```
hex_array = [hex(x)[2:] for x in dec_array]
```

Comment: What if `x` is negative?

Comment: hey that works great, why is each hex value in single quotes?

Comment: [80, 66, 67, 86, 53, 49, 46, 48, 123, 175, 13]
['50', '42', '43', '56', '35', '31', '2e', '30', '7b', 'af', 'd']

Answer (score 1):

Or use hex , which must work.

```
>>> d = 30
>>> hex(d).split('x')[1]
'1e'
```

For negative I found this solution

```
def tohex(val):
  return hex((val + (1 << 64)) % (1 << 64)).split('x')[1]
```